# chrome behaviour when writing indexeddb. "data may be stale"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium, indexeddb, localforage

I have an app which downloads 1000 small images and writes them to indexedDb (using localForage). Upon the completion of the download, and the 1000 indexedDb `setItem`s, I look in the devtools and the database is empty. I see the message "Data may be stale". Clicking "Refresh database" makes no difference. If I load a copy of the app in a second window, it sees an empty database. After a minute or so of reloading the 2nd window, the data appears.

Can anybody explain what I'm seeing, and if there any optimisations I can apply to have the data available more quickly?

Answer (score 2):

That means that indexeddb data in the developer tools are not latest, it mght be old. So clicking on refresh icon will fetch latest data and the warning about stale data will be gone.
it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It means that the indexedDb has detected an data that is not in syn with your present project. Also, be sure to include a break statement if your using a switch statement

Check out this link for more info
[Data may be stale](https://github.com/ujjwalguptaofficial/JsStore/issues/58)